# I am running an Infinite For loop in Windows form app, which is causing UI to not loading a form properly

Tags: c#, for-loop, wpf-controls

I Have a Windows form app, i am running a infinite loop(For lopp) which is causing a form to not loading properly, cant get all the objects in the form. I am a newbee to this PC language, can anyone suggest a workaround to use a loop and still can get a form loaded completely.

This is what I have it right now.

namespace Mifare1K
{
public partial class Mifare_1K : Form
{ public Mifare_1K()
{
InitializeComponent();

```
}
    private void Mifare_1K_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bConnectedDevice = false;
        cbxMass2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cbxSubmass2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        txtBoxDataOne2.MaxLength = 32;
        txtBoxDataTwo2.MaxLength = 32;
        txtDataThree2.MaxLength = 32;
        txtKeyA2.MaxLength = 12;
        txtKey2.MaxLength = 8;
        txtKeyB2.MaxLength = 12;
        txtInputKey2.MaxLength = 12;
        this.Shown += new EventHandler(Init);
       
    }
    private void Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        
       ** for (; ; )**
        { 
            //somecode here!!!!
            if (ReadReqResult == true)
            {

                //setup parameters for app
               ** for (; ; )**
                {
                    if (!bConnectedDevice)
                    {
                        some code here
                        {
                            some code here
                           ** break;** //break on some condition which does not always true
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          
                            // MessageBox.Show
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rf_ClosePort();
                        
                    }                      
                }

                pSnr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataBuffer);
                // Console.WriteLine("Done!");
               ** break;** ////break on some condition which does not always true
            }
            
           // Console.WriteLine("Not Done!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's winforms, why tag wpf-controls?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you don't want any loops in event handlers. If you need one, you need to outsource the logic to another thread or the thread pool or go async.

Comment: I am a newbee to c# language, can you add some example code here for reference that i can use it

Comment: You dont need an example for `do not use a loop`, just dont use a loop. Whatever you ae connecting to and reading will very likely have events to inform you when something needs to be done, use those instead of a loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinForm And Looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916096/winform-and-looping)

Comment: I have an application where I need to keep checking whether the reader has something or not, there is a chance that sometimes the reader would not have anything to read and sometimes it does there is no input to pc that the reader has something and I can pull it off, so I need to use a loop or some kind of solution that can keep pulling a data from the reader whether its there or not.

Comment: Check the link I posted above and see if the answer related to implementing a timer will work for you. Sounds like a timer should help you.